# I'm adding a src attribute using Jquery, but it works differently. Why?

Tags: jquery

When I set the source of the image beforehand in the html, I am able to get the original width and height. If I set the source of the image using javascript/jquery, I am unable to get the original width and height. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  var originalWidth = $('#test').prop('naturalWidth');
  var originalHeight = $('#test').prop('naturalHeight');
  console.log(originalWidth + " x " + originalHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="test" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png">
</div>
```

The above way works, but I want to add the source image using javascript. But when I try that, it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').attr('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png'); 
    var originalWidth = $('#test').prop('naturalWidth');
    var originalHeight = $('#test').prop('naturalHeight');
    console.log(originalWidth + " x " + originalHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
      <img id="test">
    </div>
```

As you can see, it returns the values 0 and 0, unlike the previous snippet. Why? and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the code is too fast and the image has not loaded yet when you try to access the properties

Add a load handler before the change of the src

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test').on("load", function() {
    var originalWidth = $('#test').prop('naturalWidth');
    var originalHeight = $('#test').prop('naturalHeight');
    console.log(originalWidth + " x " + originalHeight);
  })
  $('#test').attr('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="test">
</div>
```